# I'm not sure why this if statement isn't work

Tags: c, char, cs50, string-literals, equality-operator

Why isn't this working?

I think the logic in this if statement is flawed but I'm sure exactly what's wrong.

edit: i forgot to add the header files as well as int main(void). everything should be there now

```
int main(void){
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
string word = "APPPLE";
string alphabet[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
"P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};


    if (word[0] == alphabet[0])
    {
        printf("this program works");
    }
}
```

Comment: `word[0]` and `alphabet[0]` are of different types.

Comment: First of all, C doesn't have a type like `string`. Secondly, if the compiler doesn't complain about the non-standard type (for example if you're including the dreaded `cs50.h` header file) then the compiler should have complained about the comparison. Read the warnings and errors the compiler tells you, they are important.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally include a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. Especially if you are using a non-ISO C header such as `cs50.h`, then we need to be able to see that.

Comment: For the moment, ignore the `string` from `cs50.h`.  If `word` is any type (let's call it T), then the declaration `T word` declares `word` to be of type `T`, while `T alphabet[]` delcares `alphabet` to be of type `array of T`.  As such, `word[0]` is clearly a different type than `alphabet[0]`.  But `alphabet[0][0]` is of the same type as `word[0]`.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Do you really have your `#include` directives inside your function `main`? Please make sure that you post your actual code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer word (string is a typedef for the type char *) points to the first character of the string literal `"APPLE"`.

```
string word = "APPPLE";
```

So the expression `word[0]` has type `char`.

Elements of the array `alphabet` point to another string literals.

```
string alphabet[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
"P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
```

and have the type `string` that is `char *`.

In the if statement you are trying to compare a character `words[0]` with a pointer `alphabet[0]`

```
if (word[0] == alphabet[0])
{
    printf("this program works");
}
```

that does not make a sense.

What you need is the following

```
if (word[0] == alphabet[0][0])
{
    printf("this program works");
}
```

Though it would be better to declare the array alphabet like

```
string alphabet = {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
```

In this case the if statement will look like

```
if (word[0] == alphabet[0])
{
    printf("this program works");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that really helped me understand. I had a feeling that might have been the reason why things weren't working

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built name called "string" in C.
Instead, a character array is used for handling strings.
The following code might help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

     char word[] = "APPPLE";

     char alphabet[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

     if (word[0] == alphabet[0]) 

        printf("this program works");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP is probably using the [CS50 library](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/) (which is not part of ISO C), in which `string` is a `typedef` for `char *`. However, OP has not confirmed yet whether this is true or not. Therefore, in my opinion, the question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: Meanwhile, OP has confirmed that they are using the CS50 library. Therefore, using `string` is not wrong. Whether it is meaningful to use this `typedef` is another question, though.